# adding security parameter to a webservice client in java that its implemented in E-BUSINESS with role-base approach

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I want to implement web service client with the wsdl that its created with
E-BUSINESS suite.the authentication parameter are added to this wsdl with 
role-base approuch or active-base because it does not have any tag with this name in SOAHEADER XML but for result it needs them.
how can i add username and password to web service in my java codes.
this is soaHeader xml...
[image]